# How to apply a summarization measure to matching data.frame columns in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a hypothetical data-frame as follows:

```
# inventory of goods            
year    category    count-of-good
2010    bikes       1   
2011    bikes       3   
2013    bikes       5   
2010    skates      1   
2011    skates      1   
2013    skates      0   
2010    skis        0   
2011    skis        2
2013    skis        2
```

my end goal is to show a stacked bar chart of how the `%-<good>-of-decade-total` has changed year-to-year.

therefore, i want to compute the following:

[image]

now, i should be able to `ggplot(df, aes(factor(year), fill=percent.total.decade.goods) + geom_bar`, or similar (hopefully!), creating a bar chart where each bar sums to 100%.

however, i'm struggling to determine how to get `percent.good.of.decade.total` (the far right column) in non-hacky way.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr to compute the sum:

`library("dplyr")
newDf=df%>%group_by(year)%>%mutate(decades.total.goods=sum(count.of.goods))%>%ungroup()`

Either use mutate or normal R syntax to compute the "% good of decade total"

Note: you have not shared your exact data-frame, so the names are obviously made up.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$decades.total.goods <- with(df1, ave(count.of.good, year, FUN = sum))
df1$decades.total.goods
#[1] 2 6 7 2 6 7 2 6 7
```